# c# - Tray Icon not showing

Tags: c#, notifications, system-tray, tray

I have a NotifyIcon set up on my main form, however when the form ran the notification icon doesn't appear?

I have it's visible attribute set to true and if I try to show a balloon tooltip:

```
ntiTrayIcon.ShowBalloonTip(1000, "Info:", "Double click this icon to close AlwaysOnTop", ToolTipIcon.Info);
```

That doesn't show either.

What's the problem?

Some Info on the form:
It's a SizeableToolWindow and it has no control box or caption (so it shows up as just the borders) and it gets hidden after a while (it's essentially a splash screen that registers some global keyboard hooks), would this be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add this line in your form constructor

```
trayIcon.Icon = new Icon(SystemIcons.Application, 40, 40);
```

Comment: Can't say I thought of this, don't know how I missed the fact it didn't have an icon :( Many thanks :D

Comment: Sorry, it was too soon after answering to accept it when I posted, I've done it now though :D

Comment: And for those planning to write something like `trayIcon.Icon = new Icon("App.ico")`, make sure that your installer packages that file or your customer will have no tray icon.